# How do I get a BCMWL4306 wireless card working?

Tags: drivers, broadcom, wireless

I need the driver for my wireless chip, and I don't know where to get it. Can anyone help?

P.S. The driver needed is a BCMWL4306. Also, tell me if I need to use NDISwrapper.

Comment: Is it a BCMWL4306? I had that problem for a while, when I get home I'll see if I can find the right firmware.

Comment: Yes it is a BCMWL4306. thx.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem. my wifi card wasn't b43legacy, it was b43. I got it working from there. Thanks, anyway! :) – LinuxLover55 Jan 19 at 0:05

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my friends compaq (I don't remember the model), worth a try.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then you can activate the broadcom driver. (I would pop up or go to Dash-home then additional drivers)

Comment: I checked Add'l Drivers and the only thing I saw was the drivers for my nvidia graphics card which I already installed ;) Anyway, got anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The driver for your card is the b43legacy.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

Then load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe b43legacy
```

And check if you can find the interface

```
ifconfig -a
```

Let me know if it worked.

Regards

Comment: That didn't quite work, but thanks for the suggestion. I put the line into the terminal and it seemed like it downloaded but when I went to add'l drivers, nothing new was there.

Comment: Hello! I updated my answer with other instructions. Can you please try this?

Comment: It worked! Hallelujah! wlan0 appeared with the eth0 and lo. I will see if I can detect my wireless network at my house.

Comment: It didn't quite work because my laptop still says that there is firmware missing for the wireless stuff. It says (in network settings), "device not ready (firmware missing)" Still don't get it. Any more detailed instructions? ;)

Comment: Hello all. I fixed the problem. my wifi card wasn't b43legacy, it was b43. I got it working from there. Thanks, anyway! :)